# Passing variable name as id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am appending the checkboxes in a particular class using some function.. I have a function to run everytime the checkbox is selected.. So I need to get the name and id of the Checkboxes..

Heres the part of the code where I am appending the checkbox dynamically.. Here **value** is the one I want the id and name attribute to be..

Comment: You don't have any id in your checkbox

Comment: I don`t have any ID.. But I want the 'value' as my ID...

Comment: It's not clear what your question is...

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(brandNameg, function(key, value) {

        $(".fpblocks .fpblocksBrands_inner ul").append("<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox'  onclick='selectMainBrand(\"" + value + "\");' />" + value + "</label>");

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

set the id using

```
$.each(brandNameg, function(key, value) {
    $(".fpblocks .fpblocksBrands_inner ul").append('<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="' + value + '"  onclick="selectMainBrand("' + value + '");" />' + value + '</label>');
});
```

Comment: I used like this input = '<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" onclick="selectScatterMainBrand(' + b.name + ' );" />' + b.name + '</label>' .. It`s showing unterminated string literal..

Comment: I can call the function like function selectScatterMainBrand(ids) {

 console.log(ids) } Isn`t? It`s prompting the error in the index.html : 1 ?!

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectMainBrand(ids) {
    $('#Brands').on("change", "input", function () {   
        console.log("called");
        var selected = this.name;
        console.log(selected);
    });
}
```

I'm assuming your UL tag has id="brands". If not change the above code as follows

```
    $('.fpblocks').on("change", "input", function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(brandNameg, function(key, value) {

        $(".fpblocks .fpblocksBrands_inner ul").append("<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' id ='someID' name ='someName' />" + value + "</label>");

    });
```

and on checkbox click..

```
$(".fpblocks .fpblocksBrands_inner ul :checkbox").live('click', function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id'); //get id of checked checkbox
  var name = $(this).attr('name');   //get name of checked checkbox


})
```

Comment: insead of '.live' you should use '.on'.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

- remove `onclick='selectMainBrand(value);'` from inputs' generation code
- After checkboxes are generated, you can select name and

  $('#Brands input').on("change", function () {
      var name=$(this).attr("name");
      var id=$(this).attr("id");
      alert(name);
      alert(id);
      console.log(selected);
  });

  see the **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/BbtEG/

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamically created html (`<input type='checkbox'  onclick='selectMainBrand(value);' />`) does not have a `name`, or an `id`. You cannot pass what doesn't exist. To solve this, generate a `name` and an `id` to use.

Also in your `selectMainBrand` function you don't appear to be using the `ids` parameter that you're passing in. All that function is doing is binding a handler to the input which, since you're using `on` to bind it, seems silly.

Why not use `on` to delegate the handler instead? If you delegate the handler, you can grab the `name` or `id` from within the handler thereby obviating the need to pass those in as parameters (**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ua45/1/)**).

```
$.each(brandNameg, function (key, value) {
    var label = $('<label />').addClass('checkbox'),
        input = $('<input />').attr({
            "type": "checkbox",
            "name": "mainBrand" + key, //set the name, appending the key to make it unique
            "id": "mainBrand" + key //set the id, appending the key to make it unique
        });
    $(".fpblocks .fpblocksBrands_inner ul").append(label.append(input).append(value));
});
//delegate the change handler
$('.fpblocks .fpblocksBrands_inner').on("change", '#Brands input', function (e) {
    var selectedName = this.name,
        selectedId = this.id,
        isChecked = this.checked;
    console.log(JSON.stringify({
        "called": true,
        "selectedName": selectedName,
        "selectedId": selectedId,
        "isChecked": isChecked
    }));
});
```

If you truly have your heart set on passing in the parameters, there are ways to do that, such as binding the handler within the loop where you create the inputs (**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ua45/2/)**):

```
$.each(brandNameg, function (key, value) {
    var label = $('<label />').addClass('checkbox'),
        input = $('<input />').attr({
            "type": "checkbox",
            "name": "mainBrand" + key, //set the name, appending the key to make it unique
            "id": "mainBrand" + key //set the id, appending the key to make it unique
        }).click(function (e) {
            var self = $(this), // capture the input as a jQuery object (typically very useful)
                actualHandler = function (id, name) {
                    // do stuff
                    console.log(JSON.stringify({
                        "called": "actualHandler",
                        "selectedName": id,
                        "selectedId": name,
                        "isChecked": self.prop('checked')
                    }));
                };
            actualHandler(this.id, this.name);
            // or
            actualHandler(self.attr('id'), self.attr('name'));
        });
    $(".fpblocks .fpblocksBrands_inner ul").append(label.append(input).append(value));
});
```

or you could set the `onchange` attribute in the loop where you create the inputs (**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ua45/3/)**):

```
window.inputHandler = function (id, name) { // must be added to the global scope, otherwise it won't be visible.
    // do stuff
    console.log(JSON.stringify({
        "called": "inputHandler",
        "selectedName": id,
        "selectedId": name
    }));
};
$.each(brandNameg, function (key, value) {
    var label = $('<label />').addClass('checkbox'),
        input = $('<input />').attr({
            "type": "checkbox",
            "name": "mainBrand" + key, //set the name, appending the key to make it unique
            "id": "mainBrand" + key, //set the id, appending the key to make it unique
            "onchange": "inputHandler('" + "mainBrand" + key + "', '" + "mainBrand" + key + "')"
        });
    $(".fpblocks .fpblocksBrands_inner ul").append(label.append(input).append(value));
});
```

and there are other ways to go about it.

Personally, I would use the delegation.